# how can i add data from a dataframe to a dictionary using For

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Im trying to add all data from my dataframe "tabela_proje" to a dictionary

the data frame is like this

```
    NOME       DESCRIÇÃO
0   PRO-NO-FEN  FENDI
1   FORMAÇÃO    NaN
2   PRO-NO-170  NaN
3   PRO-NVS-SCY STADE CHARLETY
```

i tried using a for loop:

```
for i,j in tabela_proje.iterrows():
 dados = [j.to_dict()]
```

Im recieving this:

```
[{'NOME': 'PRO-NO-CBD', 'DESCRIÇÃO': nan}]
```

But instead of getting all data from the dataframe i only get the last row of data from the dataframe, can anyone tell what´s wrong please?!

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example *as text* and show the matching expected output ?

Comment: it gave me this"{'NOME': ['PRO-NO-INT', 'PRO-NO-TRN', 'PRO-NO-SLG', 'PRO-NVN-MIR', 'PRO-NVS-SCY'], 'DESCRIÇÃO': ['INTERNO', 'TRAINING', 'LG PROMOTIONS', 'MIRADOUX', 'STADE CHARLETY']}"

Comment: Thanks and can you show your expected output (*based on this example*) ?

Comment: what i want to recive is in the question, im rcieving the right thing but the problem, is that i want all data not just only the last row, because im gonna insert that dictionary into a table in postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, there is no need to loop here, just use a *list-oriented* [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) :

```
out = df.to_dict(orient="list") #orient="dict" by default
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

{'NOME': ['PRO-NO-FEN', 'FORMAÇÃO', 'PRO-NO-170', 'PRO-NVS-SCY'],
 'DESCRIÇÃO': ['FENDI', nan, nan, 'STADE CHARLETY']}
```